# What is a simple, yet proper, way to add a container to a pre-exisiting object in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would you recommend adding a container, such as a dictionary, to a preexisting object in python?  I was just messing around with a `Line2D` object from matplotlib and I found that I could add a dictionary via the following approach

```
import matplotlib as mpl
line2D_obj = mpl.lines.Line2D([0,1], [0,0])
line2D_obj.labels = dict( text = '$\delta$', ndx = 30, leader_length = 15, leader_angle = 120)
```

The `line2D_obj` did not have the method `.labels` when it was instantiated.  I just created `.labels` because I wanted to store some data in the `Line2D` object.  Is this a good approach?  If not, what else do you suggest?

In case it matters, the reason I am looking into this is I am trying to create a custom function to label `Line2D` objects in matplotlib.  Previously, I was thinking I would  just hand my labeling function a bunch of nested lists, a.la.

```
labels = [[[axis1_curve_1_label], [axis1_curve2_label]], [[axis2_curve1_label]]]
```

but this is messy and hard to follow.  I now think there is a better way.  My plotting code outputs the data axes as a list of axes called `data_ax`, so the `Line2D` objects are nicely organized into a list called `lines`.  For example, if I want to label curve 3 on data axes 2, I can simply type

```
data_ax[2].lines[3].labels = dict( text = '$\delta$', ndx = 30, leader_length = 15, leader_angle = 120)
```

It is very clear which curve I am labeling.  I can then just pass the `data_ax` object into my labeling function, and it can pick off the label info for each curve.

Comment: The normal means of creating attributes, `self.foo={}` inside `__init__`, is actually doing exactly the same thing you're doing here. The difference is that people expect to see attributes created in `__init__`, but don't expect to see them in some random code outside the class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with any object with a `__dict__` attribute.  To wit:

```
class Holder:
    pass

my_holder = Holder()

my_holder.stuff = 'stuff'
```

or even

```
import itertools

itertools.bongos = 'BONGOS'
```

Should you do this?  Probably not.  It obfuscates your code mightily.  If you are the only person to ever look at your code, you can get away with it, but it's not a good habit to get into.  Just leverage python collections like `dict` and `tuple` like they were meant to be used.  You're covertly using a `dict` in your example, might as well explicitly use one to map `Line2D` objects onto their respective labels.

```
l2d_labels = {}
l2d_labels[line2D_obj] = labels #labels having previously been defined
```

Or even a `namedtuple`, which specifies a loose contract for the object you're creating:

```
from collections import namedtuple
ll2D = namedtuple('Labeled_line2D',['line2D_obj','labels'])
```

Now you can make as many `ll2D` objects as you want, and anyone who comes along and looks at one of those objects is going to see exactly what it is: a `line2D` object paired with its `labels`.

Comment: You should explicitly say to use the `Line2D` objects as keys.

Comment: thanks.  I thought that is what you were imply, sorry if I was wrong and came across as needlessly bossy, but if that _was_ what you were implying I didn't want to post an almost identical answer.

Comment: @roippi @tcaswell Thanks for your suggestions.  Unfortunately, the `Line2D` objects are embedded in data_axes objects.  I was hoping to preserve and utilize that structure.  I should have described the original motivation behind my question more clearly.  Sorry.  I just updated the post above.

Comment: @roippi Can you explain why it obfuscates my code to add a `dict` to  an object?  Is it because people do not expect to see attributes added outside the class definition, as abarnet commented above?

Comment: @Stretch that, and generally the Principle of Least Astonishment.  If I'm a guy who is familiar with matplotlib, I know what to expect out of a `Line2D` object.  If I then see you referring to some `.labels` attribute of `Line2D` somewhere in your code I then do one of two things: 1) have a moment of self-doubt, go check the matplotlib docs, and get confused when I don't find what `labels` is.  or 2) be annoyed that I have to search through every line of your code to find out exactly what you did.  Neither is good.